# PDF Form date fields- calculate date 15 days later than entered date

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, editor

I’m trying to create a pdf form that has a date that is entered by the user and another field auto populate for 15 days after that date. I found this which appears to be what I want but I keep getting the error “syntax error: missing ) after argument list 1: at line 2.

```
var date = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy",
  this.getField("Date1").value);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 180)
if (this.getField("Date1").value != "") {
  event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", date)
}
else {
  event.value = ""
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. That'll help to get the issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. You can assign `this.getField("Date1").value)` to another variable and use that later.

```
var getDate = this.getField("Date1").value;
var date= util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", getDate);
if (getDate != "" && date != null) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+180); // i actually don't know why you used 180 here instead of 15
    event.value=util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy",date);
}
else {
    event.value="";
}
```